# ng-grid unable to get items from selectedItems inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

**main.js**

```
(function(){
    var myModule = angular.module("myModule",["ngGrid"]);
    myModule.controller("listController", ["$scope", "$log", function($scope, $log) {
        $scope.mySelections = [];
        $scope.myData = [{descripition: "product 1"}, {description: "product 2"}];
        $scope.gridOptions = {
             data: "myData",
             multiSelect: true,
             selectedItems: $scope.mySelections
        }

        $scope.start = function() {
         // Even though the grid rows are selected, length is always zero. Dont know why
         $log.info($scope.mySelections.length);
        }
    });
});
```

**index.html**
// Showing just the relevant code

```
<div ng-controller="listController" class="row">
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
<!-- This shows up correctly -->
<pre>{{mySelections}}</pre>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="start()"></button>
</div>
```

**Question:** I get the selected items in "mySelections" on index.thml but the array appears to be empty inside the "Start" function of "listController". Have been trying to solve the issue for few hours and dont understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the added comments to your code:

```
(function(){
    var myModule = angular.module("myModule",["ngGrid"]);
    /* on below line I removed your declared dependencies as are not needed (["$scope", "$log", ...) they get injected by angular*/
    myModule.controller("listController", function($scope, $log) {
        $scope.mySelections = [];
        /*here was a typo: descripition vs. description*/
        $scope.myData = [{description: "product 1"}, {description: "product 2"}];
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: "myData",
            multiSelect: true,
            selectedItems: $scope.mySelections
        }

        $scope.start = function() {
            // Even though the grid rows are selected, length is always zero. Dont know why
            $log.info($scope.mySelections.length);
        }
    });
/*added final () for self invoking*/
})();
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the description typo and self invoking paranthesis. Actual code doesn't have those issues though. Regarding "$scope" and "$log" they are passed in to avoid issues with minification. go to http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 to read on "Minification".

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using the following:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("mySelections", function(newValue, oldValue){
                $log.info($scope.mySelections.length);
            });
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of going about it. <s>But it does the job for now</s>. Waiting for a better explanation to my question or different way of handling this. Thanks.

**Update:** That didnt help either. In the start() function $scope.mySelections still shows up am empty. Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with this code:

```
var mModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
mModule.controller('listController', function($scope,$log) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    age: 50
  }, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    age: 43
  }, {
    name: "Jacob",
    age: 27
  }, {
    name: "Nephi",
    age: 29
  }, {
    name: "Enos",
    age: 34
  }];

  $scope.mySelections = [];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    multiSelect: true,
    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections
  };

  //setup some default selections
  $scope.$on('ngGridEventData', function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(0, true);
    $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(2, true);
  });

  //count all selected rows
  $scope.start = function() {
    alert($scope.mySelections.length+' rows selected');
  };
});
```

Not sure why, because it seems to be the exact code from your question (except for the module and controller definitions) but this works very well. Maybe you shouldn't use the safety wrapper???

[Look at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NPm5Am20RTfUPdejxBgK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this from the code:

```
$scope.mySelections = [];
```